# How to serialize java objects as field.path = field.value

Tags: java, serialization, reflection

I have the following model classes:

```
package com.ab.model;

import java.util.List;

public class Request {

    public Request(String requestType, Body body, List<String> emails) {
        this.requestType = requestType;
        this.body =body;
        this.emails = emails;
    }

    private String requestType;
    private Body body;
    private List<String> emails;

    public String getRequestType() {
        return requestType;
    }

    public void setRequestType(String requestType) {
        this.requestType = requestType;
    }

    public Body getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(Body body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

    public List<String> getEmails() {
        return emails;
    }

    public void setEmails(List<String> emails) {
        this.emails = emails;
    }

}

class Body {

    private String content;
    private List<Header> headers;

    public Body(String content, List<Header> headers) {
        this.content = content;
        this.headers = headers;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
    public List<Header> getHeaders() {
        return headers;
    }
    public void setHeaders(List<Header> headers) {
        this.headers = headers;
    }   

}

class Header {

    private String headerName;

    public Header (String headerName) {
        this.headerName = headerName;
    }

    public String getHeaderName() {
        return headerName;
    }

    public void setHeaderName(String headerName) {
        this.headerName = headerName;
    }

}
```

And the following instance of the Request class:

```
Request request = new Request(
                "get", 
                new Body("abcdefg", 
                        Arrays.asList(new Header("header_one"))), 
                Arrays.asList("a@a.com", "b@b.com"));
```

Do you know any library or algorithm that can serialize the request object into the following string?

```
requestType = "get"
body.content = "abcdefg"
body.headers[0].headerName = "header_one"
emails[0] = "a@a.com"
emails[1] = "b@b.com"
```

I know I can serialize it as json, xml, etc, but these don't fit my use case.
Basically I need a serialization like:
field.nestedField.reallyNestedField = "its primitive value"

As a next step, I am planning to read the generated string and generate arbitrary data for each field/nestedField then deserialize it back using PropertyUtils from Apache e.g.:

```
PropertyUtils.setProperty(requestObject, "requestType", "random type");
PropertyUtils.setProperty(requestObject, "body.content", "random content");
//...
```

Many thanks!
Andrei

Comment: any updates on this? did you get to a solution?

Comment: Just a note that once you have your dot-notated paths, you might want to use `BeanUtils` as `PropertyUtils` does not perform type conversion when setting properties.

Answer (score 0):

What about overriding your `toString()` default methods to read and output your member variables as text. You can use `super` to refer to your SuperClass and it's members.

PS: You don't have default constructors in your classes! In case you have constructors with your argument list it is suggested to include your no-argument default constructor in your class! Especially in case you are implementing some logic related to serialisation / deserialisation!

Comment: Can't do that. The classes I need to serialize are not under my control. They have default constructors though.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate and recurse on the class/object properties using Commons `PropertyUtils`.

Depending on how complex your implementation is, you might need to do some type checking for primitive/wrapper/collection types (the below leverages Commons `ClassUtils`).

```java
public static List<String> getPropertyDescriptorPaths(Class<?> clazz) {
    return getPropertyDescriptorPaths("", clazz);
}

private static List<String> getPropertyDescriptorPaths(String prefix, Class<?> clazz) {
    List<String> paths = new ArrayList<>();

    PropertyDescriptor[] descriptors = PropertyUtils.getPropertyDescriptors(clazz);

    for (PropertyDescriptor pd : descriptors) {
        if (isSimpleType(pd.getPropertyType())) {
            paths.add(prefix + pd.getName());
        } else if (!pd.getName().equals("class")) {
            paths.addAll(getPropertyDescriptorPaths(pd.getName() + ".", pd.getPropertyType()));
        }
    }

    return paths;
}

private static boolean isSimpleType(Class<?> clazz) {
    return ClassUtils.isPrimitiveOrWrapper(clazz) || clazz.equals(String.class) || isCollectionOrArray(clazz);
}

private static boolean isCollectionOrArray(Class<?> clazz) {
    return isCollection(clazz) || clazz.isArray();
}

private static final List<Class<?>> COLLECTION_TYPES = Arrays.asList(new Class<?>[] { List.class, Map.class, Set.class });

private static boolean isCollection(Class<?> clazz) {
    for (Class<?> eachClass : COLLECTION_TYPES) {
        if (eachClass.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The condition for comparing property name to `class` is because each object has a `getClass()` method, and we don't care about that.

Using this with your classes, we get the result:

```java
System.out.println(getPropertyDescriptorPaths(Request.class));
// [emails, requestType, body.headers, body.content]
```